# Trendline is not showing when displaying data

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization, trendline

The trendline is not showing when querying data from MySQL. The month and the result is both in integer format. Attached is the image of the chart and the trendline is not working. Can help me on this?

The coding part is like this:

```
<?php
   include ('connection.php');
?>


<html>
   <head>
      <title>Google Charts Tutorial</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
      </script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.google.com/jsapi">
      </script>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});    
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "container" style = "width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
      </div>
      <script language = "JavaScript">
       function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', 'Performance %'],
         <?php
          $query = "SELECT month , result_ind FROM performance GROUP BY month";


          $exec = mysqli_query($db,$query);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)){


          echo "['".$row['month']."',".$row['result_ind']."],";
         }
        ?>
       ]);



            // Set chart options
            var options = {
               'title':'Month vs %',
               'width':550,
               'height':400,

                trendlines: {
                0: {
                type: 'exponential',
                color: 'green',
                visibleInLegend: true,
      }
    }  // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
            };


            // Instantiate and draw the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('container'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
         }
         google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the image that trendline not showing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trendline only only works on a continuous axis (number, date, etc...)

not on a discrete axis (string)

as such, you will need to remove the single quotes from the x-axis values, here...

```
echo "[".$row['month'].",".$row['result_ind']."],";
```